# Asking for analysis of sentences

Tags: syntax, grammar, applied-linguistics, grammatical-subject, field-linguistics

Could you tell me what the difference nominal  WH clause and  nominal relative clause is ? For example, nominal WH clause : no one knows what caused  the accident.  Nominal Relative clause:  You call him whatever you want.  How can I distinguish between the two.
Another thing is the function of this sentence : [What I need most is a good rest] S. So , does the whole sentence function as a subject. That's what I have read. Thank you

Comment: I don't understand your example "WH: no one knows the accident".  This seems to be a formula of some sort rather than an example.

Comment: I hope I made it clearer.

Comment: Sorry, user11223, you're still not making sense. Part of the problem is that _No one knows the accident_ doesn't make much sense: I can just about imagine some context where it might, but without context, I don't know what it means. Your mention of "nominal WH clause" makes me guess that you are assuming that "the accident" is a transform of a WH clause like _what the accident [something]_, but I can't think of a [something] that might be implied by _No one knows the accident_.

Comment: You're apparently asking about free relatives; and you're interested in the difference between "who" and "whoever"? Is that what you're after?

Comment: I am asking about the difference between a WH clause and a relative clause?

Answer (score 1):

In "You call him whatever you want" the "whatever you want" is a noun phrase consisting of a relative clause -- there is no noun head.  Similarly, in "What I need most is a good rest" the subject noun phrase "what I need most" is a relative clause with no head noun.

However, in "No one knows what caused the accident", there is no relative clause.  Instead, "what caused the accident" is an indirect question.  "What caused the accident?  Nobody knows."

Comment: I can notice a small diferrence now. Could you classify these sentences please?  1- We are to accept unconditionally what proposal you are willing to make .2- Here is  where you will find her at this time of night.

Comment: I'd better not try -- I find the distinction difficult, and I might make a mistake.  Do searches on "free relatives" and "embedded or indirect questions" and you should get some good information.